# flow text in columns in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

As title says, is this possible? Actually I'm interested to know if there are any other GUI toolkit or interface languages that can accomplish this. The only one I'm aware of is HTML+CSS3..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [Multicolumn text in the JEditorPane/JTextPane](http://java-sl.com/multicolumn.html) by @StanislavL very useful.